# JSP can't display Russian characters

Tags: java, html, jsp, encoding, character-encoding

I have a JSP file that contains paragraphs with Russian text. However, no matter what I do I can't get a browser to display that text - instead all I get is hieroglyphs.

The same text but in a simple HTML file without any headers or declarations works fine:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>some russian text</body> 'is displayed fine
</html>
```

But the moment I save that file as JSP and try to view it in a browser the text gets broken.

I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also I tried

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

But neither works. My file is in `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsp is most likely not using `utf-8` ,try

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```